# Use addEventListener on a class not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to convert my script using `addEventListener` with `getElementById` on a `var` for a `getElementByClassName` but this doesn't work. How to fix it?

See my code

JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementByClassName('myClass');

_slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {

    var value = values[handle];

    if ( handle ) {
        input.value = Math.round(value);
});

input.addEventListener('change', function(){
    _slider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
}, false);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" class="myClass">
```

This script work perfectly if I find my div with an `ID`, but not work with a `CLASS`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no getElementByClassName. There is getElement**s**ByClassName that returns a collection. If there is only one, than select the first index.

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[0];
```

Other option is querySelector

```
var input = document.querySelector('.myClass');
```

My guess is that you do not have just one element, but multiple, than you need to loop over the collection.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
//or
//var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
for( var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function() { console.log(this); } );
}
```

Comment: Thx for yours answer, i have already try 

var input = document.querySelector('.myClass');

But i work only for first class elements, i try too with querySelectorAll but this didn't work

Comment: And your issue when doing that? If you have more than one element, you need to loop over the collection. There is no bulk add events

Comment: You know an other alternative use jquery ?
I try with .class() but didn't work too,
M constraint is grunt restrict usage of function in a loop because is  not a good practice

Comment: If you have jQuery, you can use jQuery. `$(".myClass").on("click", function(){});` Under the hood it does the same thing. You need to use a loop to add events to multiple things. That is how it works. There is no batch event. You can use event delegation which checks to see if the event is an element you want to monitor. `$(document).on("click", ".myClass", function(){});`

Comment: Thanx for everyone, finally i swap way for returning with ID, sorry for loosing your time.

Regards
- - - -
William R

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = document.getElementById('id_name')
```

...here addEventListener will work because "id" will unique but in case of "class" there might be same values entered...
So you have to select which element you want to manipulate...example ==>

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[0] // after this addEventListener will work.
```

Hope this might help you :)