# addEventListener with onchange not working

Tags: javascript

I'd like to show name of the city after click on checkbox

I have very simple table :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Y</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" ></td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" ></td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" ></td>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>I</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

AND JS code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("check").addEventListener("change", function() {
            var parent = this.parentNode;
            var city = parent.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;

            alert(city);
});
```

And this code not working. Why ?

Regards

Comment: because `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list, not a single node - you need to iterate through the node list, adding the event listener for each item in the list

Comment: getElementsByClassName will return an array. You will have to loop over them and set it individually

Comment: @Rajesh: It's not an array.

Comment: My bad. It returns a Node List.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431983/use-addeventlistener-on-a-class-not-working

Comment: Your browsers Developer Tools console would've alerted you to the source of the problem

Comment: OK, now I understand. Thanks for help !